If $G$ is $p$-stable then $G/O_{p'}(G)$ is also $p$-stable.
I am trying to understand a proof of the lemma in the picture, but I could not understand the underlined parts. Mainly I have two questions.

Probably the author considers an action of a certain group on $\text{Syl}_p(PK)$ and makes the underlined conclusion, but I could not get the action and the reason behind the conclusion.

Secondly in the last part of the proof he is probably using the Dedekind's Lemma. My question for this part is: If $P$ is any $p$-subgroup of  a finite group $G$ then is it always true that $N_G(P) \cap O_{p'}(G)=1$ ?


Thanks for any help. 

Where is this lemma from?

From Topics in Finite Groups by Terence Gagen p. 83

What is the definition of $P$ in the first part? The second part you ask about seems to be just $N_G(P) \cap C_G(P)K = C_G(P)(N_G(P) \cap K)$, then note that $N_G(P) \cap K$ centralizes $P$. Indeed $K$ is normal so $[P, N_G(P) \cap K] \leq P \cap K = 1$, assuming $P$ is a $p$-group.

The answer to the question you pose in 2 is surely No. Trivial counterexample $G=C_2$, $p=3$. It will fail every time that elements of $O_{p'}(G)$ normalise $P$ and you get easy counterexamples by looking at direct products of arbitrary groups with $p'$-groups.

For question 1, $A$ is a $p$-group, so when it acts on any set $X$, we have $|X^A|\equiv|X|\pmod{p}$. Now if $X$ is the set of Sylows of $PK$, then $|X|\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, so there's a fixed point. Conjugating $A$ can make that fixed point $P$ (since $K$ acts transitively on $X$).

In the first part assuming $A$ is a $p$-group, you have an action of $A$ on $p$-Sylows of $PK$ by conjugation. A $p$-group acting on a set $\Omega$ with $p \nmid |\Omega|$ has a fixed point on $\Omega$. Then note all $p$-Sylows of $PK$ are of the form $P^k$ for some $k \in K$, by Sylows theorem.

Thank you so much for your helpful comments @testaccount and Steve D
